# Prove subset sum of squares errors are less than sum of squares error of the original set

Tags: statistics, proof-writing, sums-of-squares

As part of a proof I'd like to show if $R_1 \cup R_2 \subseteq R_3$, then $SSE(R_1) + SSE(R_2) \leq SSE(R_3)$ where SSE is the sum of squared deviations from the mean of each group.  I'm assuming the values of the group are real or rational numbers if that makes a difference.

I know that since the mean minimizes the sum of squared errors, then each group must be minimized, I'm stuck on how to leverage the fact that the groups are subsets to show that $SSE(R_1 \cup R_2) \geq SSE(R_1) + SSE(R_2)$.  Is there a basic piece of theory I am missing?  Any pointers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your insight about the mean being the estimator that minimizes the sum of squared errors we can write:

$$SSE(R_1 \cup R_2) = \min_\gamma \sum_{R_1 \cup R_2}(x_i - \gamma)^2$$

Now we can split this sum into two components:

$$= \min_\gamma \sum_{R_1}(x_i - \gamma)^2 + \sum_{R_2}(x_i - \gamma)^2$$

But of course, minimizing each sum individually will always give a value at least as small as minimizes the two sums together:

$$\geq \min_\alpha \sum_{R_1}(x_i - \alpha)^2 + \min_\beta\sum_{R_2}(x_i - \beta)^2$$

But this is exactly $SSE(R_1) + SSE(R_2)$

Comment: Thank you for the response!  It's not quite clear to me why minimizing each sum of squares individually is at least as small as minimizing the sum of squares together.  Like if I had the integers from [-5, 5] and I took 6 of them randomly in one group and the other 5 in another group, why should SSE of the groups individually be smaller than the union?

Comment: Minimizing $f(x)+g(x)$ is different than minimizing $f(x)$ then minimizing $g(y)$ separately then taking the sum, right? If $a$ is the point which attains minimum in the first case, then certainly we can do just as well in the latter case, no? Hopefully that gives some more insight.

Comment: can I interpret it as because $\gamma$ is the overall best minimizer for the entire group, whatever we choose for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ must necessarily be worse?

Comment: If by worse you mean "gives a smaller value" then yes.